# How to highlight objects that repeat within 30 days by conditional format?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

How can i highlight objects that appears within 30 days by conditional format in google sheet ?

Column A contain date and Column B contains objects.

(only objects need to get highlighted)

thanks in advance. here a link shared to the sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bdWKHtW6SA6XI5pIZUrlLQJLi-Gywx2iYUqxFWY1e0I/edit#gid=0

one more sheet added ('estimated output') where you can see how the output must be. please have a look. thank you

Comment: Edit your example to show what you are hoping the calculation to be. Which of the rows would be highlighted?

Comment: @pgSystemTester thanks for that suggestion and i have added a sheet named 'estimated output'. so that you can see how the output must be. please have a look. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, there are two conditions that must be met for a cell to be highlighted:

- The object inside the cell must be repeated in that column.
- A date between an object must be 30 days apart from the date of a repeated object.

This behavior can be accomplished with the following formula, which you can plug in as a [custom formula in a Conditional Formatting rule](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cuse-custom-formulas-with-conditional-formatting):

```
=AND(COUNTIF(B$2:B$7,B2)>1,COUNTIF(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B$2:B$7=B2,ABS(A$2:A$7-A2),false))),30)>0)
```

The first part (`COUNTIF(B$2:B$7,B2)>1`) makes use of the [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) formula to ensure that the object is repeated (that there are more than one instances of it). The second part uses an [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) to enumerate the differences between dates with an [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) clause to make sure those dates correspond to the same object, and then the [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) formula is used again to check that there is at least one instance of those differences being 30. Finally, those two conditions are combined with an [AND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301?hl=en) formula.

Comment: can u please apply that formula in that sheet mentioned? when i tried to do it's not working.